# QT QWebView print on multiple pages with page number

Tags: qt, qwebview, qpainter, qprinter

I have tried to print page numbers while printing out page from QWebView, The blank pages are coming out. Also help on How to keep a block of text in same page when the block is getting split partially in two pages.

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape);
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);

QString pdfName =QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(0,
                                              tr("Save pdf"),
                                              QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(),
                                              tr("PDF Files (*.pdf)"));
if( pdfName == "" )
    return ;
printer.setOutputFileName(pdfName);
QWebPage page;
ui->webView->resize (printer.paperRect ().size ());
page.setView (ui->webView);
QPainter painter;
painter.begin (&printer);
page.mainFrame()->setHtml ("&lt;h1&gt; Page 1 &lt;/h1&gt;");
page.mainFrame()->render (&painter);
printer.newPage();
page.mainFrame()->setHtml ("&lt;h1&gt; Page 2 &lt;/h1&gt;");
page.mainFrame()->render (&painter);
painter.end ();
ui->webView->print(&printer);
```